# keyPressEvent called after the button is released

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to change cursor icon when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is pressed. The problem is, that if you press and hold down a button, the keyPressEvent method is not called. If you press two buttons at once, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then it works as expected.

Test environment: system SUSE 12.2, python 3.6.4, pyqt5 5.11.3 (also tested pyqt5 5.9.2).

This is a minimal (not)working example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print('Press')

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('Release')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Once pressing and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, the 'Press' should be printed. However, it is not until you release the button or click another one simultaneously.

I noticed different behavior for different keys. Both left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> behave the same, also the left <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> behaves as desired.

Comment: With PyQt5 5.13 on Linux, "Press" is printed when I press Ctrl

Comment: I will try PyQt5 5.13, I am unable to right now because of some libdbus-1.so.3 relocation error.

Comment: Tested with PyQt5.9.1 and py3.6.3 on Windows: it prints both "Press" and "Release" as expected. I wonder if it's just due to the buffering in `print` - maybe try adding `flush=True`. Or ignore that if the print was just for demo.

Comment: If it was just the buffering, that at least the QApplication.setOverrideCursor would work as expected. However that is not the case. Maybe the problem is the system QT version, which I have pretty old (5.6.1). I don't know, how much the pyQT5 depends on the system QT5.

Comment: @DavidSery PyQt depends 100% on Qt, because it is just a thin wrapper around its libraries. Anyway, I tested using pyqt-5.6/qt-5.6 and also pyqt-5.13/qt-5.13 on linux (with an openbox window manager), and I cannot reproduce the behaviour. Please edit your question and add details about the specific platform(s) you are testing on (including the desktop environment). Could there be some programs you have running in the background that are stealing the keystrokes or messing with the keyboard focus?

Answer (score 1):

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    print('Press')
    QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)

def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
    print('Release')
    QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

Comment: It seems that you have not understood the question, the OP indicates that keyPressEvent is called only after releasing the Ctrl key but it is normal to invoke keyPressEvent when you just press that key.

Comment: The problem is not that I don't know how to change the cursor, but that the signal does not get called until the button is released or a second one is pressed. I still have to test a new PyQT5 version, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: for me the `keyPressEvent` function is called when i pressed the button and `keyReleaseEvent` is called when i released.